# How to tell webpack to preprocess a yarn package with flow annotations?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, flowtype, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

I am currently having a client side application which uses `React`, `flow` types and I package it using `webpack 3.11` and everything is working great so far.

Just because the app is starting to get a little too big, I decided to move some React components to their own package by moving them to their own folder, setting up a `package.json` and then installing them by doing `yarn add ./path/to/package --dev` and after that webpack started complaining because it could not parse my flow annotations.

**Error example**

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import "./BaseTree.css";
| 
| export type Tree = {
|   name: NodeName,
|   parent: ?NodeName,
```

I've read about compiling my assets and using the stripped down javascript in my app but that's an extra building step I'd rather avoid since I don't plan on using this package anywhere else and my webpack setup already handles flow types just fine on it's own.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current",
          "browsers": ["last 3 versions"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "jest",
    "react",
    "flow"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js** (as generated by `@symfony/webpack-encore`)

```
{
  "context": "/vhosts/app",
  "entry": {
    "main": "./assets/modules/main.js",
  },
  "output": {
    "path": "/vhosts/app/public/build",
    "filename": "[name].js",
    "publicPath": "/build/",
    "pathinfo": true
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": {},
        "exclude": {},
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "babel-loader",
            "options": {
              "cacheDirectory": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": {},
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "/vhosts/app/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js",
            "options": {
              "omit": 1,
              "remove": true
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "style-loader?sourceMap"
          },
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "minimize": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": {},
        "loader": "file-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "images/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
          "publicPath": "/build/"
        }
      },
      {
        "test": {},
        "loader": "file-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "fonts/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
          "publicPath": "/build/"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    {
      "filename": "[name].css",
      "id": 1,
      "options": {
        "allChunks": false
      }
    },
    {
      "entriesToDelete": []
    },
    {
      "opts": {
        "basePath": "build/",
        "publicPath": "/build/",
        "fileName": "manifest.json",
        "stripSrc": null,
        "transformExtensions": {},
        "writeToFileEmit": true,
        "cache": null
      }
    },
    {
      "options": {
        "debug": true,
        "options": {
          "context": "/vhosts/app",
          "output": {
            "path": "/vhosts/app/public/build"
          }
        },
        "test": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "options": {}
    },
    {
      "definitions": {
        "$": "jquery",
        "jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
      }
    },
    {
      "paths": [
        "**/*"
      ],
      "options": {
        "root": "/vhosts/app/public/build",
        "verbose": false,
        "allowExternal": false,
        "dry": false
      }
    },
    {
      "definitions": {
        "process.env": {
          "NODE_ENV": "\"development\""
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "compilationSuccessInfo": {
        "messages": []
      },
      "shouldClearConsole": false,
      "formatters": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
      ],
      "transformers": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
      ]
    },
    {
      "outputPath": "public/build",
      "friendlyErrorsPlugin": {
        "compilationSuccessInfo": {
          "messages": []
        },
        "shouldClearConsole": false,
        "formatters": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null
        ],
        "transformers": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "devtool": "inline-source-map",
  "performance": {
    "hints": false
  },
  "stats": {
    "hash": false,
    "version": false,
    "timings": false,
    "assets": false,
    "chunks": false,
    "maxModules": 0,
    "modules": false,
    "reasons": false,
    "children": false,
    "source": false,
    "errors": false,
    "errorDetails": false,
    "warnings": false,
    "publicPath": false
  },
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".js",
      ".jsx",
      ".vue",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "alias": {}
  },
  "externals": {}
}
```

**TL;DR version**

Have app written using `flow` types. 
Also have own npm package written using `flow` types to be used just on that app. 
Can I set up webpack so that it strips the types for both my app code and the package?

Comment: Please post `webpack` configuration.

Comment: Added `webpack` configuration as generated by `encore`